# For loops & If Statements

Tags: php, checkbox, echo

I'm working on this code in PHP and basically I have 5 checkboxes, for 5 individual items, each called "ItemCheck" and they have values of 0-4. Now I wrote a code where it has it so it displays the numbers that are checked from those 5 check lists.

**Form:**

```
for ($i=0;$i<count(5);$i++){
echo "
<input type='checkbox' name='ItemCheck' value='$i.check'>$i</input><br>"}
```

**PHP Process:**

```
if (isset($_POST['ItemCheck'])){

    for ($o=0;$o<$ItemCount;$o++){

        if($_POST['ItemCheck'] == $o.'.check') {
            echo "Item " . $o . "<br>";

            }
    }
} 
else{ echo "You must select at least one product";}
```

Although say if I check box #1,2 & 3, the final output will only display "Item 3". Now matter how many checkboxes you select, it will only display the one with the highest value and none other. Does anybody know what's wrong with the code and how to have it so it displays each individual number that's selected, and not just the one with the highest value?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is set the name of the checkbox element `ItemCheck[]` this will make `$_POST["ItemCheck"]` an array.

Example:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count(5);$i++){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ItemCheck[]' value='$i.check'/> $i<br>";
}
```

Another thing to note is the browser won't post up anything for an unchecked checkbox so I think your processor needs to be like this.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ItemCheck'])){
    for ($o=0;$o<count($_POST['ItemCheck']);$o++){
            echo "Item " . $_POST['ItemCheck'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "You must select at least one product";
}
?>
```

Another thing so make sure of is that your form has the method set to `POST`

Comment: Dude you just passed my rep count, in 21 days, which I accumulated in 9 months. What is your trick?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work. I played around with the code (and the other previous code for the form) but they output was just the else statement.

Comment: update the question with the  html for the form... we can see if something jumps out

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm very grateful for your help! I tried to use the code you gave me so I can get it to display "Item '#'" instead of just listing the amount of items there are? ex: if there's 3 items selected, it displays Item 0 - Item 2. But do you know how I can get it so it displays the number of the item I selected.

That's the reason why I had if statement earlier, but if it's too much work then it's okay. 

Again I appreciate your help a lot!